# Expand LibreOffice calc filter box

Tags: libreoffice

When filtering on a column where all the values start with the same string, it is impossible to use the filter box easily:

[image: Filter box on LibreOffice calc]

I wish there was a handle at the tip of the red arrow, that would allow me to resize the box and see the full line of each item in the filter list.

Is it possible?

I'm running LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible as of Libreoffice 5.2. However, it is a very good idea and should be reported as an enhancement request here:
https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/

Note that when you mouse hover (meaning letting your mouse over a specific entry for a few seconds) the full text of the entry will appear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As a faster alternative to hovering, I'm using `shift`-scroll to scroll horizontally.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez that is a nice alternative (particularly since my mouse has horizontal scroll with the wheel. Never, had noticed. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! :) [Bug 104408](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104408) submitted.

Comment: The bug was marked as a duplicate of a 4-year old one. That doesn't look so good :(